# PyTest and Multiline outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pytest

I am writing some PyTest for a script I have pretty much already written, to prove it works. Returns from the first funcion is in the form of a list so that's fine but func2 is another matter as it returns a multi-lin answer and I can't find anything to get around that little fact. My attempt, which makes the most sense to me is:

```
x = '''
The X axis is: >Head

X = ABCA
The Y axis is: >Header

Y = ACCA 

ACCA
====|
A--A|A
----|B
-CC-|C
A--A|A
'''

def test_result_of_outter_dotplot():
    assert outter_dotplot(['A', '-', '-', 'A', '|A\n', '-', '-', '-', '-', '|B\n', '-', 'C', 'C', '-', '|C\n', 'A', '-', '-', 'A', '|A\n'],'ABCA', 'ACCA') == x
```

Anyone have an idea of where to go from there?

Func3 creates an ascii version of the plot so this would also answer that and then Func4 creates a matplotlib graph so if you have a clue of where to go with that they pray tell because at the moments I'm going to test the inputs of a plt.imshow and use those to confirm the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, turns out I was getting ahead of myself and adding stuff into it that are not added until the end.

```
x = '''ACCA
====|
A--A|A
----|B
-CC-|C
A--A|A
'''

def test_result_of_outter_dotplot():
    assert outter_dotplot(['A', '-', '-', 'A', '|A\n', '-', '-', '-', '-', '|B\n', '-', 'C', 'C', '-', '|C\n', 'A', '-', '-', 'A', '|A\n'],'ABCA', 'ACCA') == x
```

This is correct and there for multilines do indeed work as I thought.